# Error while creating PHP extension for openCV

Tags: php, opencv, php-extension, face-detection

I am working on a project based on OpenCv. I have tried to use http://www.xarg.org/project/php-facedetect/ library for that. I have tried to create php-facedetect extension, But its not working correctly, its showing the errors as follows

```
OpenCV$ sudo phpize && ./configure && make && make install /
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
./configure: line 1962: config.log: Permission denied
./configure: line 1972: config.log: Permission denied
```

Can anyone helpe me solve this, I have also tried https://github.com/mgdm/OpenCV-for-PHP, Its also showing the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like configure does not have permission to write to the log file.

Try running each of the commands individually with sudo like this:

```
sudo phpize
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Normally you can skip sudo for all but the install step like this:

```
phpize
./configure
make
sudo make install
```